# How can I make the H1 tag responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello everyone my question is as follows. How can I make the H1 tag responsive so that it doesnt shift boxes on my image. I am using bootstrap 4.5.2 for my project.

**Here is an image on the pc version**
[image]

**Here is an image on the mobile version (the H1 tag has shifted 1 box to the left)**
[image]

**Here is my html code**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    officeMap
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">officeMap</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
                <img src="PlanPage/Resources/grid.png" alt="officeMap" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="room1"><h1>1</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
body {
    background-image: url('Resources/blurred_desk1.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.room1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 12%;
}
```

**The image im using**
https://hbr.org/resources/images/article_assets/2013/04/grid.png

Comment: you use `left: 12%;` and the parent is probably the full width of your screen so it will take 12% from the screen width. I will need your full css (preferrably a snippet) to actually help you

Comment: I updated the css part and put in my whole css file. The parent could be the bootstrap modal right? since the image is in the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried like this and it worked.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    .room1 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 12%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 990px) {
    .room1 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 18%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 989px) {
    .room1 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 30%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use percentage values and expect them to behave this way.

You can use `flexbox` and set fix size for image and shrink `h1` to get remaining width with `flex-shrink-1`.

Something like this:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/chalist/pen/dypVyaJ)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am trying to keep the H1 tag in the box. Not outside of it. Is there a way to do this?